# How does humidity affect the dielectric constant of a material?

Tags: capacitance, dielectric, humidity

I'm trying to figure out how a humidity sensor using a Capacitor works, and every document I have managed to find seems to come to the conclusion that an increase in humidity causes the capacitance to increase Linearly.

However, I haven't been able to find a direct "formula" or dependence between humidity and dielectric (or Capacitance). Going through research papers, I have found that increased water vapor causes the dielectric value to increase; however, I have not been able to find whether this relation is linear, exponential, or varies by material.

I am ideally trying to find a material in which this relation is linear, so that, loosely,

Dielectric Constant $= k \cdot H)$

($k$ is a constant, $H$ is humidity)

Comment: The capacitors that I have seen are sealed.  How do you propose to expose a capacitor dielectric to humid air?

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the dielectric constant and humidity definitely depends on the material. Usually at higher humidity concentration more water molecules are absorbed by the material as compared to lower ones. The relationship is more likely to be non-linear (exponential) if considering the whole humidity range (0 - 100%). However, it may look linear in close ranges. If you draw a calibration curve of the capacitance as a function of humidity you might extract a relationship for your material.